# Can't update Jenkins on Debian

Tags: jenkins, cicd, debian-buster

Every couple of weeks on my personal server, I go and update my Jenkins to the latest version. Over the past few weeks, the server has stated that Jenkins is already at the latest even though new versions have been released on jenkins.io. Looking for some assistance on what I'm doing wrong.

My Jenkins instance:
[image]

Command I run:
`sudo -- sh -c 'rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives; apt-get update; apt-get upgrade -y; apt-get dist-upgrade -y; apt-get autoremove -y; apt-get autoclean -y; rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives'`

Result I receive:
`jenkins is already the newest version (2.403).`

On Jenkins.io:
[image]

Maybe related, I did update the cert per these instructions https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2023/03/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/. During that somehow my instance flipped from LTS to Weekly

Comment: I can't comment on the LTS/flip issue at the end, but for the 2.403 vs. 2.405 only a remark: 2.403 is the version reported latest by the package manager you're using. 2.405 is the version reported latest by the web console you're using. That are two independent systems. Double check with your package manager you're using the correct repository. The package manager will always report the latest version in the repository that it is using for the package. I.e. if this is a debian repository, it will only see updates if the debian package manager updated the repository.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.

Had to run the weekly `Debian/Ubuntu weekly release` commands in the "Signing keys changing" link above to get it to work.